# Simple List search Using Match (How To use in alternating Cells)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, counter, offset

I am using A Named range with the following in

```
=OFFSET('Staff List ML'!$A$1,MATCH('Sick & Off track'!$B$1&"*",'Staff List ML'!$A$1:$A$955,0)-1,0,COUNTA('Staff List ML'!$A:$A))
```

This then related back to the first cell "B1" on 'Sick and Off track' and allows the user to input part of a name and then the code looks up the name relating to the part name.

the problem with this is that i cannot get it to do the same when i drag the Cell B1 Down (to fill all the cells in Row B).

Any ideas how to make it so that the named ranged is a little more dynamic?

thanks all!

***EDIT***

Basically B1 contains ="NAMED RANGE" the NAMED RANGE had the formula in, this basically cross references anything that has been input into B1 and generates a drop down List with the first match/Second Match/Third Match ect. it cross references from "Staff List ML" which is Row A Names Row B managers Row C Depot. Row D Code. This all works fine. The problem is where i am migrating this method to another Book it simply wont work in other cells (Because it initially references B1 in the Named range (See formula)). I hope this explains a little more of what this does and what i want it to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically and *why*? Can you please provide sample data and expected results?  It's a bit unclear what you're asking, and it sound suspiciously like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Dont Worry, I fixed it. It was simply that in each new Sheet the first cell i am referencing needs to be related back to the named range.